# Mounting a drive via systemd unit file on CoreOS unsuccessful

Tags: systemd, coreos

When I'm trying to mount a formatted drive via a systemd unit (from my `cloud_config`):

```
- name: var-lib-ceph-osd-ceph\x2d1.mount
  command: start
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Mount Ceph disk (/dev/sdb) to /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-${host.id}
    Before=docker.service
    [Mount]
    What=/dev/sdb
    Where=/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1
    Type=btrfs
    User=64045
    Group=64045
```

but unfortunately if fails with a `status=217/USER` error.

```
$ systemctl status "var-lib-ceph-osd-ceph\\x2d1.mount"
â var-lib-ceph-osd-ceph\x2d1.mount - Mount Ceph disk (/dev/sdb) to /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/var-lib-ceph-osd-ceph\x2d1.mount; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-01-22 12:32:04 UTC; 33s ago
    Where: /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1
     What: /dev/sdb
  Process: 833 ExecMount=/bin/mount /dev/sdb /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

$ sudo /bin/mount /dev/sdb /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1

$ ls -la /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1
total 5242936
drwxr-xr-x 1 64045 64045        238 Jan  6 10:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 64045 64045       4096 Jan  6 10:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root           0 Jan  6 10:49 async_snap_test
-rw-r--r-- 1 64045 64045         37 Jan  6 09:43 ceph_fsid
drwxr-xr-x 1 64045 64045      49782 Jan  7 12:14 current
-rw-r--r-- 1 64045 64045         37 Jan  6 09:43 fsid
-rw-r--r-- 1 64045 64045 5368709120 Jan 21 07:56 journal
-rw------- 1 64045 64045         56 Jan  6 09:43 keyring
-rw-r--r-- 1 64045 64045         21 Jan  6 09:43 magic
-rw-r--r-- 1 64045 64045          6 Jan  6 09:43 ready
drwxr-xr-x 1 64045 64045         26 Jan  6 09:43 snap_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 64045 64045          4 Jan  6 09:43 store_version
-rw-r--r-- 1 64045 64045         53 Jan  6 09:43 superblock
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root           0 Jan  6 10:49 sync_snap_test
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root           0 Jan  6 10:49 test_subvol
-rw-r--r-- 1 64045 64045          2 Jan  6 09:43 whoami
```

If I execute the mount command manually, it works without problem. Somebody got an idea wha't wrong? Google hasn't got much to offer unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one is probably not allowed to use

```
User=64045
Group=64045
```

Once I removed this, I was successfully able to start the unit.